# Error checking in controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, error-handling

I'm discovering ASP.NET Core MVC and I'm on my first project. Creating a cool web shop.

I'm currently wondering how to implement faulty information checking for example in the controller

Let's say there a product page, whenever users clicks on a product they will hit the function below.

As you can see the function accepts an int parameter named id, it will search in the database for the id that fits the `productId`, but I'm wondering how do I add error checking here? Like for example if the `id` does not exist in database return to page XX?

Also feel free to give suggestions to the function if you don't like it.

I've already tried to do a simple if and else statement

```
if(productvm == null) 
{
    then
    return RedirectToPage("Index")
}
else  
    return View("ProductPage", productVm);
```

but it didn't seem to hit the if statement

```
[Route("ProductPage/{id}")]
public IActionResult ProductPage(int id)
{
    Product product = _uow.Products.SelectProduct(id);

    var stockViewModels = new List<StockViewModel>();

    foreach (Stock stock in product.Stock)
    {
        stockViewModels.Add(new StockViewModel()
            {
                Id = stock.Id,
                Description = stock.Description,
                IsAvailable = stock.IsAvailable,
                Quantity = stock.Quantity,
            });
    }

    ProductViewModel productVm = new ProductViewModel
        {
            Name = product.Name,
            Id = product.Id,
            Description = product.Description,
            Price = product.Price,
            Stocks = stockViewModels,
        };

    if (productVm == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("Productslist");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ProductPage", productVm);
    }
}
```

I basically want an error handling the controller if the id is not found in the database then execute XX

The way how I test the function is to change the `ID` when browsing the page with an ID that does not exist in the database, then I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3I1i.png

and I want to handle it

Comment: can you show the full codes for your logic? I didn't see any `if...else..` in your above code?

Comment: Yes edited post, basically the if statement is never getting going to hit when i set a breakpoint

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you have new the `productVm` object before the `if`, so it will never be null, for your case, you should get check the product object and not the `productVm`, for example:

```
    Product product = _uow.Products.SelectProduct(id);

    if (product == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("Productslist");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ProductPage", productVm);
    }
```

Comment: changed it to your solution, then i get this error when entering a faulty product id https://i.imgur.com/k8daTU8.png

Comment: NVM you were right , imade a typo. instead of redirectToPage i should've used redirectToAction